# ng-init passing argument throws Syntax Error, unrecognized expression

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs controller bound to my element like this

```
<div ng-controller="mycontroller" ng-init="initialize('Type A')" >
 <div ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I have my initialize function implemented as part of $scope

```
$scope.initialize = function(type) { ... do something... }
```

I get a runtime error in Chrome stating the following

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   div:has([ng-repeat='task in tasks'])[ng-init='initialize('Type
>   A')']

The code works fine, and does what it should. But why I do see this in Dev Tools?

Comment: That `div:has` is a bit of a red flag. What version of Angular? You know you shouldn't be using `ng-init` for this sort of thing. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: Maybe Type A is not a String.. try doing ng-init="initialize(Type A)"

Comment: The `div:has` makes it look like you are using jQuery or a library that is using jQuery. Are you? And in what way?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that `Visual Studio` was attaching something quirky to the browser using some SignalR implemented hooks. The way VS did that was by injecting some JS code based on what was in DOM which faltered. That masterpiece of Microsoft is called `BrowserLink`.

I disabled BrowserLink by clicking on little Undo-like button next to Start button and choosing "Disable BrowserLink"

[Here is more information on how to disable it](http://www.poconosystems.com/software-development/how-to-disable-browser-link-in-visual-studio-2013/).